# How do I change the title of a tab in a tabbedpanel in Apache Wicket?

Tags: java, wicket, tabbed

I have a TabbedPanel in which I dynamically add and remove tabs. In addition I want to change the title of a tab according to its changing contents. In my current code the title is set by the Wicket ID like:

```
public class GenericTab extends AjaxTab {
private boolean closable = true;

public GenericTab( MyAbstractPanel myPanel ) {
    super( Model.of( myPanel.getTitle() ) );
}
```

So I can set the title once at instantiation. How can I change it with Java code?

Answer (score 1):

```
public GenericTab( MyAbstractPanel myPanel ) {
  super( new PropertyModel<String>(myPanel, "title") );
}
```

Comment: How does this approach help me to modify the title later?

Comment: Check https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Working+with+Wicket+models#WorkingwithWicketmodels-DynamicModels. PropertyModel is a dynamic model, so if you change MyAbstractPanel#title with your APIs then automatically the new title will be used by the tab's title.

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend an AjaxTabbedPanel and override the `newTitle` method like this:

```java
            @Override
            protected Component newTitle(String titleId, IModel<?> titleModel, int index) {
                Label updatableLabel = new Label(titleId, titleModel) {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(IEvent<?> event) {
                        super.onEvent(event);
                        Object payload = event.getPayload();
                        if (payload instanceof MyAjaxEvent) {
                            ((MyAjaxEvent) payload).getTarget().add(this);
                        }
                    }
                };
                updatableLabel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
                return updatableLabel;
            }
```

After that you can update a tab title with

```java
send(getPage(), Broadcast.BREADTH, new MyAjaxEvent(target, model));
```